# Orientation cursor is gone

Tags: transforms

[image]

"**This**" is missing in my project and I can't get it to reappear in my project. I am able to move the object by dragging it with my mouse but the drag axis isn't there so I can't do stuff with precision.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have probably accidentally turned off the gizmos by clicking on the icon arrowed below:
[image]

Comment: Everything in my gizmos tab is already turned on. I have no idea as to what caused it to disappear. It happened when I just had used the knife tool to cut up some things and entered object mode for the first time in a while.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix it by restarting Blender, the only thing I hadn't done.

Comment: That was the next thing I was about to suggest! Glad it's working for you now1